# How to add line-breaks when echoing from a txt file using php?

Tags: php, html, css, txt

So I have been starting on some php recently and made a page where people can type a text and then when they click save everyone on that page sees that text displayed under somewhere, after the text gets writen to the txt file by a php code I use another php code in my home page code that gets the text and 'echoes' it onto my page.

This code looks like that:

```
<?php

$bestand = fopen("tekst.txt", "r");
$tekst = fread($bestand, filesize("tekst.txt"));
fclose($bestand);
echo "<p style='
      margin-top: 5%;
      color: #04AA6D;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
' id='tekst'>" . $tekst . "</p>";

?>
```

```
The tekst file looks like this:
Test
Test
Test
Test
```

But when it echoes it onto my page it all gets put into one string. like this:
Test Test Test Test

what is the easiest way to force php to add line breaks where they need to be.
Any help would be really nice as im just starting out on php and I really cant find a answer.

Comment: You can use `nl2br()`, it should work

Comment: You need to use both `htmlspecialchars()` and `nl2br()`. Also, `file_get_contents()` is a less convoluted way to read the whole file at once. Of course, you'll still get white-space collapsed because that's how HTML works.

Comment: So what do I need to replace in my existing code, because I tried to add things like nl2br(), butt those dont really work.

Comment: @BoDijkhuizen Trust me, they really work: https://3v4l.org/YNMd4#v8.2.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my previous comment and @Álvaro González comment, you can maybe try this:

```
$tekst = file_get_contents("tekst.txt");
$tekst = htmlspecialchars($tekst);
$tekst = nl2br($tekst);
echo "<p style='
      margin-top: 5%;
      color: #04AA6D;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
' id='tekst'>" . $tekst . "</p>";
```

Comment: You're a hero, it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.